# Why doesn't Droggeljug like yellow broccoli?

Tags: edna-and-harvey-new-eyes

I am playing *Edna & Harvey: Harvey's New Eyes* and don't understand the solution to the pizza puzzle:

**SPOILER WARNING**

I have to make a single pizza with 4 toppings for a group of 4 uniquely "colour-blind" people. Each has their own like and dislike, and their own pair of colours that they mix up.

Adrian wants tomatoes, but no blueberries.
Petra wants broccoli, but no tomatoes.
Droggeljug wants banana, but no broccoli.
Peter wants blueberries, but no banana.

Adrian mixes up his reds and yellows.
Petra mixes up her yellows and greens.
Droggeljug mixes up his greens and blues.
Peter mixes up his reds and greens.

We have all four toppings available, and are able to change their colour (to red, yellow, green or blue) through a process of dyeing that we shan't speak about. Bleh.

I tried a few ways of reasoning through this puzzle. For example, if Adrian mixes up red and yellow, we can dye his tomatoes yellow. He'll think they're red tomatoes, and Petra won't recognise them. But none of my approaches worked as expected, so I [resorted to a walkthrough](http://www.gameboomers.com/wtcheats/pcEe/EdnaHarvey2/EdnaHarvey2.htm) that gave the following solution that I do not understand:

> Adrian mixes red and yellow colors. He wants tomatoes and no blueberries on his pizza. So he should have green tomatoes.
>   Peter mixes red and green colors. He wants blueberries and no bananas on his pizza. Red and green makes blue. So he should have yellow blueberries.
>   Petra mixes yellow and green colors. She wants broccoli and no tomatoes on her pizza. So she should have blue broccoli.
>   Drogglejug mixes green and blue colors. He wants bananas and no broccoli on his pizza. So he should have red bananas.

Can someone take me through the logic that arrives at this answer?

Answer (score 3):

It's because though they're uniquely colour-blind, in the way that they actually don't see things in the two colours, rather than mixing them up.  So with Adrian, he can't see things that are yellow and red.  If you put regular, red tomatoes on, he wouldn't see them if they're on the pizza, and they'd upset Petra since she can see them.  If you dye them yellow, while Petra can't see them, neither will Adrian.  If you dye the tomatoes a colour Adrian can see and Petra can't, then they're both happy, since he know's they're on there and she doesn't.  So that's why you dye the tomatoes green.